# Jupyter SSL Error(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1091)')

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to understand how python requests work using a jupyter notebook
The commands I'm running are:

```
> import requests 
> requests.get('https://www.ecosia.org/', verify=False)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last) ~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    695             if is_new_proxy_conn and http_tunnel_required:
--> 696                 self._prepare_proxy(conn)
    697 

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _prepare_proxy(self, conn)
    963 
--> 964         conn.connect()
    965 

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    358             if self.tls_in_tls_required:
--> 359                 conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
    360                 tls_in_tls = True

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _connect_tls_proxy(self, hostname, conn)
    501             server_hostname=hostname,
--> 502             ssl_context=ssl_context,
    503         )

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data, tls_in_tls)
    428         ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
--> 429             sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname
    430         )

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, ssl_context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    471     if server_hostname:
--> 472         return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    473     else:

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    422             context=self,
--> 423             session=session
    424         )

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\ssl.py in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
    869                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
--> 870                     self.do_handshake()
    871             except (OSError, ValueError):

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)    1138                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1139             self._sslobj.do_handshake()    1140         finally:

SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1091)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last) ~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    755             retries = retries.increment(
--> 756                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    757             )

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    572         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 573             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    574 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.ecosia.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1091)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-3-fd617f87a929> in <module>
----> 1 requests.get('https://www.ecosia.org/', verify=False)

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     74 
     75     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 76     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     77 
     78 

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 
     63 

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    540         }
    541         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 542         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    543 
    544         return resp

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    653 
    654         # Send the request
--> 655         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    656 
    657         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonMasterClass\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    512             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    513                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
    516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.ecosia.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1091)')))
```

Do I need to setup some other port for the jupyter notebook to access the internet?

Comment: Python Version is 3.7, Windows 10. Running the commands on a jupyter notebook v6.15 in a virtual anaconda env

Comment: You're running these in a jupyter notebook?  I just did tried those commands in a jupyter notebook and got a 200 response.  Are you still seeing the issue?  Re: your question of how python requests using a jupyter notebook...it would be the same as running it from a terminal or any other env

Comment: The issue got resolved. I just needed to update my requests module and anaconda navigator. Thanks for your help! :)